# Blocking locks created due to inactive session in last 2 months

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-administration

How to find the details of blocking locks due to inactive session for last 2 months ? Please help with a PL -sql code

Answer (score 0):

You can track the blocking session with such a query below

```
select ora_database_name dbname,
       v.inst_id,
       v.sid,
       v.serial#,
       v.status,
       v.username,
       v.blocking_session_status,
       v.final_blocking_session,
       v.blocking_session,
       v.blocking_instance,
       v.logon_time,
       floor(v.last_call_et / 60) "Duration (Min.)",
       nvl(v.module, v.program) Module_Info,
       nvl(v.client_info, v.osuser) Client_Info,
       v.machine,
       v.action
  from gv$session v --> gv$session is used for RAC systems
 where (v.username not like 'SYS%' and v.username != 'DBSNMP')
   and v.status = 'ACTIVE' 
   and v.blocking_session is not null
 --and sid = &sid
 --and username = upper('&schema_name')
 --and v.osuser like '%'||'&os_user'||'%' 
 --and lower(nvl(v.client_info,v.osuser)) like lower('%'||'&cli_info'||'%') 
 --and lower(module) like lower('%'||'&modul_name'||'%')          
 --and v.inst_id = '&inst_id'      
 order by "Duration (Min.)", v.username, v.logon_time desc
 -- ordering prominently by being hanged duration
```

*You can make active the commented out options whatever you need.*

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from dba_dml_locks where session_id = :p_sid;

select * from dba_ddl_locks where session_id = :p_sid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You *might* be able to find historical blocking information in the Active Workload Repository (AWR).  This query might be helpful:

```
--Blocked sessions for the past two months.
select *
from dba_hist_active_sess_history
where blocking_session is not null
    and sample_time > sysdate - interval '2' month
order by sample_time desc;
```

However, AWR is only available in Enterprise Edition, when licensed.  And by default it is only configured to supply information for 8 days.

You can investigate and increase the AWR retention period with the below code.  But keep in mind that storing extra data will use additional space in the SYSAUX tablespace:

```
--Find how long AWR retains this information.
select dbid, retention from dba_hist_wr_control;

--If necessary, change the retention period to 62 days (62*24*60).
begin
    dbms_workload_repository.modify_snapshot_settings(retention => 89280);
end;
/
```

Also, this information will only help with troubleshooting some types of locks.  AWR uses sampling, and will only catch things that are waiting on a lock for (on average) more than 10 seconds.  Some locks, like space locks, may fail immediately if the parameter `RESUMABLE_TIMEOUT` is disabled.

Also, the view `DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY` does not tell you if the blocking session was active or not.  But this view may be a good starting point for an investigation.